# Create blank file (*.docx | *.ppt | *.xlsx) using OneDrive API (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, rest, onedrive

How can I create a blank file, (*.docx | *.ppt | *.xlsx), using OneDrive API?

I am using the following URL for creating a file.

```
PUT /drive/root:/{parent-path}/{filename}:/content
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm), the request body should consist of binary stream to be uploaded. Since I want to create a new file, I send a white space as content.

It works perfectly when I do for a *.txt file like,

```
PUT /drive/root:/myFilename.txt:/content
```

But it doesn't work for any of the other file formats mentioned above. It creates a file, but when I try to open it with either Word Online or local Word, it fails to open the file.

I've tried to send the content as plain text, html-formatted text, XML-formatted text. None of them seem to work.
Any ideas on how the body content should be formatted for the file formats mentioned above or am I doing this the wrong way? Is there another way to create blank files in OneDrive?

Comment: Seems like you're creating an empty-byte Word file, which isn't a valid Word file. To make this work you'd need to know what an "empty" Word file looks like (for example, open Word, save an empty document, and then check out the byte-stream for that file).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but still no result. Doesn't open the file at all.

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive API does not support creating blank files.

As the formats of applications such as Microsoft Office are expanding and growing we would recommend you generate the file that you would like to upload first with the application that should open/modify it and then put that file on OneDrive.

This feature is available on the OneDrive website so users can quickly use the web editor experiences.